# Who SHOULD accept a taanit dibbur?

Tags: fast-days, family-members, speech-talking

If one is home with his family (especially these days when everyone is home, all day), would it be fair to his family members not to speak to them (besides strict divrei Torah)?

**EDIT:**

In what cases *would* it be appropriate? Only in a yeshiva, away from family and with understanding acquaintances?

Answer (score 2):

I don't have a textual source for you, but the *hashkafah* that I have absorbed from [my teachers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yeshivah_Gedolah_of_Johannesburg) says that you certainly have to consider the consequences of any *chumrah* that you adopt. There may be circumstances where taking on a personal *taanit dibbur* would be constructive, but it is a stringency, not required by the halachah. You have to be careful that it does not become חומרא דאתי לידי קולא, a stringency that leads to a leniency. Upsetting your family transgresses the mitzvah to make peace. If you could be **sure** they would be happy not to speak to you all day it might be alright, but that would be rare (or dysfunctional :-P ) family setup.

Comment: bh thank you! so when would the rav assume such would indeed be practical?